# Couldn't identify element on activity in Android

Tags: java, android, appium, mobile-application

I'm trying to locate an element in an Android app but unfortunately couldn't identify the locators. Refer below image of screen:

[image]

The rectangle shown in image bottom comes after click on Province dropdown. But couldn't identify which layout it is. Non of these value are identifiable. using `Appium` and `UiSelector`. It only shows `android.widget.ScrollView` as whole screen. Can someone please let me know from where these kind of content get displayed.